# Trouble with malloc for array of structs inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

```
typedef struct ListElement{
    int studid,numofcourses,postcode;
    float gpa;
    char firstname[NUM];
    char lastname[NUM];
    char deprt[NUM];
} ListElement;

typedef struct snode {
    int key;
    struct ListElement *data;
    struct snode **forward;
} snode;

typedef struct skiplist {
    int level;
    struct snode *header;
    struct snode *maxvalue; 
} skiplist;

skiplist *skiplist_init(skiplist *list) {
    int i;
    snode *header = (snode *) malloc(sizeof(struct snode) + (sizeof(ListElement)));
    snode *maxvalue = (snode *) malloc(sizeof(struct snode) + (sizeof(ListElement)));
    list->header = header;
    header->key = INT_MAX;
    header->forward = (snode **) malloc(sizeof(snode*) * (SKIPLIST_MAX_LEVEL + 1) + (sizeof(ListElement***emphasized text***)));
    for (i = 0; i <= SKIPLIST_MAX_LEVEL; i++) {
        header->forward[i] = list->maxvalue;
    }

    list->level = 2;

    return list;
}
```

I am making a skip list and i get segmentation fault. I think i am using malloc wrong, but since i am new i cant get it to work alone. Segfault pops in other function insert,but i think the faut is on this part of code.

Comment: Don't cast the output of malloc in C.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please show us a [MCVE].

Comment: You are not setting `list->maxvalue = maxvalue;` anywhere.

Comment: Also, why do you do `malloc(sizeof(struct snode) + (sizeof(ListElement)))`?

Comment: When you allocate for an `snode`, you only need `malloc(sizeof(snode))`. The `snode` only contains a pointer to a `ListElement` struct. You will have to allocate for that separately.

Comment: I still get the segfault. I removed the casts on mallocs and i use malloc twice, once for the snode and once for the inner ListElement struct. I think i allocate memory the wrong way with the forward array due to the double pointer(array of snodes)